# Why "tsfile is empty" error appeared when trying to copy tsfile (with data) from Version 0.13 to Version 1.1 of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I tried to copy the tsfile from Apache IoTDB Version 0.13 to the server of Version 1.1 and then tried to load it. However, an error popped out: `Msg: 701: TsFile/opt/software/iotdb/data/data/sequence/root.17/0/0/1691679039001-99-0-0.tsfile is empty, please check it be flushed to disk correctly`. Why is this and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This error will appear when `flush` is not executed in Version 0.13 of Apache IoTDB, or data is still writing in after `flush` is executed. If you need to migrate V0.13 to V1.1 of IoTDB, the you need to stop all your writing process, execute `flush` through Cli tool, and `load` all data from V0.13 to V1.1, finally the writing process may recover.